# WSO2 sourcecode of identity server (wso2is-3.2.3-src.zip) is always built with errors

Tags: java

we downloaded sourcecode of identity server (wso2is-3.2.3-src.zip) from wso2 website. After unzipping it it turns out its version is wso2is-3.2.0-src.

We spend more than two weeks to reference many materials online and try to build it with sufficient bandwidth. First we use ant, maven 2 and jdk jdk1.6.0_25.Then we found wso2is-3.2.0-src/products/pom.xml missed one end tag "/" and we corrected it. Then we found we must use Sri Lanka Colombo timezone based on one error. We often run out of memory, so we have to use
"export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1280m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m"
"ulimit -n 65536"
we got rid of run-out-of-memory errors. Still we failed to build it.

Afterwards we found this weblink[a link](http://docs.wso2.org/display/identity/Installing+Apache+Maven+for+Identity+Server+on+Linux) . It seemed we had to use maven 3.0.4. After setting all the environment variables, we went to  directory wso2is-3.2.0-src/  and typed in
mvn clean install

Still we ended up with a bunch of following errors. We are dubious if the sourcecode is erroneous. Have anyone built the sourcecode of wso2is-3.2.3-src.zip successfully? How should we build it?

```
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.wso2.carbon:deployment-synchronizer-feature:pom:3.2.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 22, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.server.feature:3.2.0 (/root/Desktop/wso2is-3.2.0-src/features/deployment-synchronizer/org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.server.feature/3.2.0/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.wso2.carbon:deployment-synchronizer-feature:pom:3.2.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 22, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.ui.feature:3.2.0 (/root/Desktop/wso2is-3.2.0-src/features/deployment-synchronizer/org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.ui.feature/3.2.0/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.wso2.carbon:deployment-synchronizer-feature:pom:3.2.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 22, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.ec2.client.feature:3.2.0 (/root/Desktop/wso2is-3.2.0-src/features/ec2-client/org.wso2.carbon.ec2.client.feature/3.2.0/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.wso2.carbon:ec2-client-feature:pom:3.2.0 in central [a link](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 22, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.esb.mediation.feature:3.2.0 (/root/Desktop/wso2is-3.2.0-src/features/esb-mediation/org.wso2.carbon.esb.mediation.feature/3.2.0/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.wso2.carbon:esb-mediation-feature:pom:3.2.0 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 21, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.esb.mediation.server.feature:3.2.0 (/root/Desktop/wso2is-3.2.0-src/features/esb-mediation/org.wso2.carbon.esb.mediation.server.feature/3.2.0/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.wso2.carbon:esb-mediation-feature:pom:3.2.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 21, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.esb.mediation.ui.feature:3.2.0 (/root/Desktop/wso2is-3.2.0-src/features/esb-mediation/org.wso2.carbon.esb.mediation.ui.feature/3.2.0/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.wso2.carbon:esb-mediation-feature:pom:3.2.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 21, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.wso2.carbon:carbon-parent:3.2.0 (/root/Desktop/wso2is-3.2.0-src/core/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'modules.module[41]' specifies duplicate child module org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap/3.2.0 @ line 1055, column 25
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.ui:3.2.0 (/root/Desktop/wso2is-3.2.0-src/components/registry/org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.ui/3.2.0/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'pluginRepositories.pluginRepository.id' must be unique: wso2-maven2-repository -> http://dist.wso2.org/maven2 vs http://dist.wso2.org/snapshots/maven2 @ line 68, column 17
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.wso2.carbon:carbon-features:3.2.0 (/root/Desktop/wso2is-3.2.0-src/features/pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     'modules.module[14]' specifies duplicate child module axis2-repo-mgt @ line 553, column 25
[ERROR]     'modules.module[18]' specifies duplicate child module module-mgt @ line 557, column 25
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] [a link](http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException)
[ERROR] [Help 2] [a link](http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN)/UnresolvableModelException
```

Answer (score 1):

Installing Identity Server on Linux from Source Distribution Guide [[1]](http://docs.wso2.org/display/identity/Installing+Identity+Server+on+Linux+from+Source+Distributio) may helpful.
http://docs.wso2.org/display/identity/Installing+Identity+Server+on+Linux+from+Source+Distribution

If you go inside the /wso2is-3.2.0-src/patch-releases/ folder, you will find separate directories for 3.2.1, 3.2.2 and 3.2.3 
For example, if you want to build 3.2.1,  find 3.2.1 patch releases pom.xml and (`mvn clean install` from /wso2is-3.2.0-src/patch-releases/3.2.1/ directory), then it will build following modules respectively.

```
    <module>dependencies</module>
    <module>orbit</module>
    <module>service-stubs</module>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>components</module>
    <module>features</module>
    <module>samples</module>
    <module>products</module>
```

Please note, 3.2.0 branch needs to be built with maven2.

FYI: To build current [trunk](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/), use maven3.