# Issue building wso2 carbon 4.1 from source

Tags: wso2

I have checked out the source using the instructions `svn checkout http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.1.0 wso2carbon` from here: http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Carbon410/Obtaining+the+Product

I have tried running `mvn install` using maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-8) - the install prerequisites state that version 2.1.0 or later version of maven is ok: http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Carbon410/Installation+Prerequisites

I hit the errror:

```
Component descriptor role: 'com.jcraft.jsch.UIKeyboardInteractive', implementation: 
'org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.jsch.interactive.PrompterUIKeyboardInteractive', role hint: 
'default' has a hint, but there are other implementations that don't
```

Searching on google, it seems this is a problem with maven 2.2.1 - http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/WAGON-393

So I tried with mvn 3.0.5 and run into the following error:

```
Failed tests: 
  test3(org.apache.axis2.jaxws.utility.ClassUtilsTests)
  test4(org.apache.axis2.jaxws.utility.ClassUtilsTests)

Tests run: 457, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Parent ............................. SUCCESS [0.730s]
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Resource bundle .................... SUCCESS [1.144s]
[INFO] Axiom Parent POM .................................. SUCCESS [0.590s]
[INFO] Axiom Test Utilities .............................. SUCCESS [2.559s]
[INFO] Axiom Jaxen Test Suite ............................ SUCCESS [1.380s]
[INFO] Axiom API ......................................... SUCCESS [18.402s]
[INFO] Axiom Implementation Test Suite ................... SUCCESS [2.008s]
[INFO] Axiom Impl ........................................ SUCCESS [13.743s]
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Kernel ............................. SUCCESS [16.125s]
[INFO] Axiom DOM ......................................... SUCCESS [18.484s]
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Data Binding ....................... SUCCESS [9.023s]
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Transport - Local .................. SUCCESS [2.363s]
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Transport - HTTP ................... SUCCESS [2.792s]
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Code Generation .................... SUCCESS [10.721s]
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - ADB Codegen ........................ SUCCESS [30.639s]
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Addressing ......................... SUCCESS [4.468s]
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Java2WSDL .......................... SUCCESS [6.632s]
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - tool - Repository Maven Plugin ..... SUCCESS [1.410s]
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Fast Infoset ....................... SUCCESS [13.221s]
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Clustering ......................... SUCCESS [1:10.258s]
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Scripting .......................... SUCCESS [2.957s]
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - JAXB-RI Data Binding ............... SUCCESS [10.221s]
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - SAAJ ............................... SUCCESS [17.412s]
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Metadata ........................... SUCCESS [22.842s]
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - JAXWS .............................. FAILURE [1:12.654s]
```

**EDIT: 31st May 2013**

When I run `mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true` I get a little further, but run into a new error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project axis2-transport-testkit: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/snowch/repos_thirdparty/carbon_kernel_4.1.0/dependencies/transports/1.1.0-wso2v8/modules/testkit/src/main/java/org/apache/axis2/transport/testkit/doclet/ResourceInfoDoclet.java:[27,22] error: package com.sun.javadoc does not exist
```

I'm guessing that somewhere in the source tree, someone has coded a dependency on the SUN JDK and I am running OpenJDK.

Comment: try building the latest patch release in patch-releases. also, did you try building it with tests skipped?

Comment: I have just found an answer on stackoverflow for an older version of carbon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365363/what-is-the-appropriate-way-to-build-wso2-carbon-tags